# Representability of relative spectrum of a quasi-coherent sheaf of algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, zariski-topology, representable-functor

Let $X$ be a scheme and $\mathscr{R}$ a
quasi-coherent $\mathscr{O}_{X}$-algebra. Let

$$ F: (Sch/X)^{opp} \rightarrow (Sets), \hspace{1cm} (f:T \rightarrow X) \mapsto \text{Hom}_{(\mathscr{O}_X-Alg)}(\mathscr{R},f_{*}\mathscr{O}_T)
$$

be a functor.  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3889738/how-to-reduce-to-affine-case-to-determine-whether-a-given-functor-is-representab) is adressed to representability of this functor $F$ and the [only answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3971071) contains some remarks I not understand.

We introduce there an affine cover $\bigcup_i U_i$ of $X$ and
consider the functors

$$ F_i: (Sch/X)^{opp} \rightarrow (Sets), \hspace{1cm} (f:T \rightarrow X) \mapsto \text{Hom}_{(\mathscr{O}_{X}-Alg)}((u_i)_*(\mathscr{R}\vert_{U_i}),(f_{*}\mathscr{O}_T)) $$

where $u_i: U_i \hookrightarrow X$ is the canonical inclusion.

We observe that we have for every $i$ a canonical morphism
$ \alpha_i:\mathscr{R}\to (u_i)_*(\mathscr{R}|_{U_i})$ induced
by  $u_i$. This induces a
morphism of functors $\alpha_i^*:F_i\to F$. It is claimed that
$\alpha_i^*$ is a monomorphism.

Moreover it is also claimed there that this description implies immediately that
for any $X$-scheme $f: X \to X$ we must have that
$F_i(T) \neq \emptyset$ if and only if $f: T \to X$
factors through $U_i$.

Questions:
Why is $\alpha_i^*:F_i\to F$ a monomorphism of functors? Or equivalently
why for every $X$-morphism $f: T \to X$ there is an inclusion
$F_i(T) \subset F(T)$?

Why from the construction of $F_i$ is follows that $F_i(T) \neq \emptyset$ if and only if $f: X \to X$
factors through $U_i$?

Comment: You should first try to understand the Theorem for an affine scheme $X:=Spec(A)$ - have you done this?

Comment: @hm2020: Yes, in affine case $X= Spec(A)$ for every $f: T \to X$ there is a bijection  $Hom_{(\mathscr{O}_X-Alg)}(\mathscr{R},f_{*}\mathscr{O}_T) \to 
Hom_{(A-Alg)}(B, \Gamma(T, \mathcal{O}_T)),   $
$(\phi^{\#}: \mathscr{R} \to f_{*}\mathscr{O}_T)  \mapsto (\phi^{\#}_A: \mathscr{R}(A) \to 
f_{*}\mathscr{O}_T(A))$ (we introduce notation $B:= \mathscr{R}(A)$ and by definition
$f_{*}\mathscr{O}_T(A)=\Gamma(T, \mathcal{O}_T)$)

Comment: Therefore it suffice to show that 


$ Hom_X(T, Spec(B)) \to Hom_{(A-Alg)}(B, \Gamma(T, \mathcal{O}_T)),
\ (g, g^{\#}) \to g^{\#}_A $ 

is a bijection which is functorial in $T$. But that's Proposition 3.4, p 68.